# How to prepare an angular.js app to deploy to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku

I have built an Angular.js quiz app by following a video. I don't understand the workings of the app yet, but it works fine with Mozilla Developer Edition, not with other browsers because I run it locally. My app's root directory contains the main HTML file, a JSON file, a folder for the CSS file, a folder for the images, and a folder for Angular.js files. 
When I try to deploy the app to Heroku, it gives me an error message saying 'No default language could be detected'. It has something to do with build packs. I am unable to figure it out. Here is the link to my repo on GitHub:
[My repo on GitHub](https://github.com/KaptanSingh2020/angular-quiz.git)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku supports node server so create a basic node server for your angular application

Install NodeJS and type `npm init` from project folder to initialise the package.json file.
Install these packages gzippo, express, morgan. Run this command from terminal.

```
npm install --save gzippo express morgan
```

server.js

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Create a Procfile (remember file without any extension)

Procfile

```
web: node server.js
```

Now try deploying your branch on Heroku

Comment: It worked. I had to set a build pack first. Then it was deployed successfully.